# How to get composer autoload classmap via Script\Event?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm currently getting the autoload classmap by requiring the file explicitly

```php
$map = require 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php';
```

However my class is already importing `Composer\Script\Event` class and making use of the Composer instance

```php
<?php

namespace Acme;

use Composer\Script\Event;

class Foo
{
   public static function bar(Event $event)
   {
      $extra = $event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getExtra();
      $autoload = $event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getAutoload();
   }
}
```

How can I get the autoload classmap the sameway am getting the `$extra` and `$autoload`? (without using `require`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getAutoload()` is the only way I know of to get the auto-load information from a Composer object.  I use the following function to process the result of `getAutoload()`, hopefully this is enough information to answer your question.

```
function parseAutoload(Event $event)
{
    foreach ($event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getAutoload() as $std => $lookup) {
        switch ($std) {
            case "psr-0":
            case "psr-4":
                foreach ($lookup as $namespace => $paths) {
                    if (substr($namespace, -1) != "\\") {
                        $namespace .= "\\";
                        // TODO Maybe produce a warning?
                    }
                    if (!is_array($paths)) {
                        $paths = array($paths);
                    }
                    foreach ($paths as $path) {
                        if (substr($path, 0, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
                            $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                        }
                        if (is_dir($path)) {
                            $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
                            $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
                            $regex = new RegexIterator($iterator,
                                '/^' . preg_quote($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '(.+)\.php$/i',
                                RegexIterator::REPLACE);
                            $regex->replacement = '$1';
                            foreach ($regex as $file => $class) {
                                $class = "{$namespace}" . str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "\\", $class);
                                echo "Found class '{$class}' at '{$file}'";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "classmap":
                foreach ($lookup as $class => $path) {
                    echo "Found class '{$class}' at '{$path}'";
                }
                break;
            case "files":
                foreach ($lookup as $i => $path) {
                    if (is_readable($path)) {
                        $code = file_get_contents($path);
                        $tokens = token_get_all($code);
                        // File all the classes in the file.
                        for ($i = 2; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
                            if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS &&
                                $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE &&
                                $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING
                            ) {
                                $class = $tokens[$i][1];
                                echo "Found class '{$class}' at '{$path}'";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                // TODO Maybe produce a warning?
        }
    }
}
```